# How to do multiple and different copy paste in same document?

Tags: windows-xp, productivity, portable

How to do multiple and different copy paste in same document?

In same document I need to do some changes.

All changes are different. Is there any way to do this quickly?

I need to do this in 300+ document.

Edit:

For example

I want to change this

```
function aout0() {
    out("0", 100, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout1() {
    out("1", 200, "This text is different in each file", ""); 
}
function aout2() {
    out("2", 300, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout3() {
    out("3", 400, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout4() {
    out("4", 500, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout5() {
    out("5", 600, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout6() {
    out("6", 700, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
```

into this

```
function aout0() {
    out("0", 0, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout1() {
    out("1", 136, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout2() {
    out("2", 272, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout3() {
    out("3", 408, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout4() {
    out("4", 544, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout5() {
    out("5", 680, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
function aout6() {
    out("6", 816, "This text is different in each file", "");
}
```

Comment: hmm, you mean something like an AI system that will figure out the required changes for those 300+ files? how about some details buddy.

Comment: Do you really mean copy/paste or does search/replace better describe your requirement? Also, what is the document format? An example will help us help you.

Comment: @Mike- it's a part of long JavaScript document

Comment: @Mike - I want to select all instances ( like we do using control) in same file where i need change and then paste required amends in each place , in as less as possible steps

Comment: Am I understaning you? You want to do multiple replacements in several different areas of text within each file but not necessarily ALL text of each file. You plan to open each file, select multiple sections of text and apply the replacements - as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 1):

this is a classical problem for an old tool called '[sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)'. you pipe text through this tool and can modify the text on its way out. you can get a version for windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). to fix one of your lines:

```
 % sed -i -e 's/out("0", 100/out("0", 0/' *.js
```

and repeat this for all of the patterns you want to change. you can also combine all of your relevant patterns into a .sed - file and apply them all at once.

Comment: how to use this

Comment: Akira has given you a command line, you need to download [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) for Windows XP and run it from the command prompt.

Comment: ah, the web2.0 dudes these days :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a clipboard manager like [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/)?